# android, how to separate functionality of activity over multiple classes?

Tags: java, android, mixins

I'm implementing GCM for the first time and the sample app on google provides DemoActivity which deals with GCM functionality. (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

I can copy those gcm related codes over to my MainActivity, but I 'd like to keep things separate, ie. create a separate file for gcm and let MainActivity use it.

In python world, `mixin` would be great fit here.
But I'm not sure if mixin exists for java and if its the right tool here.

How would one implement the GCM functionality in a separate class in java?

I'm thinking something like the following.

Create GcmHelper.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

-->

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, Activity activity) {

    context = getApplicationContext();
    this.mActivity = activity;
```

MainActivity::onCreate creates GcmHelper() and calls `GcmHelper.onCreate(bundle, this)`

do make similar changes for `onResume()` and activity related code to use the handed-over activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Seperate Class eg. GcmHelper
2. Make GcmHelper constructor using Context parameter
3. Copy Every GCM related functions to GcmHelper
4. Create object of GcmHelper by passing the context in MainActivity->OnCreate
5. Finally call the required methods...